# How can I get this SQL dump to import into PhpMyAdmin without this error?

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

I am trying to import a SQL dump from a live WordPress site into my local MAMP dev environment using PhpMyAdmin so I can make edits to the site locally. I keep getting this error:

> Error
> SQL query: INSERT INTO `wp_options` VALUES (259568, '_transient_timeout_geoip_98.80.4.79', '1440122500', 'no');
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1062 - Duplicate entry '259568' for key 'PRIMARY'

My knowledge of SQL is minimal. What could be causing this and what do I need to do in order to fix the problem so that I can successfully import the database and get the site up and running locally?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace `INSERT` statement with `INSERT IGNORE`. That helps import entries even if they have duplicates.

If you use unix-like OS, you can use `sed` command to replace insert:

```
cat dump.sql | sed s/"^INSERT"/"INSERT IGNORE"/g > dump-new.sql
```

Or you can add option `--insert-ignore` for [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_insert-ignore) to write INSERT IGNORE statements rather than INSERT statements.

For export via phpMyAdmin it's possible to set an option:

```
Settings -> Export -> SQL -> Use ignore inserts
```

Comment: I am not using the terminal, just phpmyadmin. The mysql dump came from a WordPress plugin as I do not have access to phpmyadmin on the server side. I usually just work with front-end stuff so I'm a bit out of my element with databases and sql. Would this command still apply within phpmyadmin? Unfortanetly I won't be able to mess with it again until I go back to work a week from Monday but it had me pulling my hair out.

Comment: But this would have to be done on the live server PhpMyAdmin? I don't have access to it at the moment... Is there anything I can do to get the current SQL dump I already have to work? I may be misunderstanding you...

Comment: I misunderstood your question about phpMyAdmin. So you import dump locally via phpmyadmin, right? If yes, please set options `Settings -> SQL Queries -> Ignore multiple statement errors`, `Settings -> Import -> CSV -> Do not abort on INSERT error` and then import dump.

Comment: Yes that's correct I have an SQL dump from the live website and am trying to import it into a local PhpMyAdmin. That sounds like what I need. What are the chances of this causing other issues? Thank you for your help

Comment: This did get the import to complete successfully however I was still having database issues. I ended up using the duplicator plugin for WordPress. Since the site was so large I had to filter out /wp-content and some other folders to get the package to build then just added them back after I restored the site. This didn't solve this particular question but at least I solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your table already has a record with a primary key value of 259568, and primary keys are required to be unique. Deleting the existing record would allow you to insert this one, but deleting the existing record may cause problems as well.